# Simulate a scrollbar without any plugins or UI - possible or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, scrollbar

I have a `div` with a list inside. The `div` is set to `overflow:hidden`. Next to the `div` I have a little handle, to control the scroll.

First of all, I want to know if it's possible to make that list scroll depending on if the handle is going up or down. But I want to do that without `overflow:scroll`, without any plugins, and without jQuery UI.

Only with pure JavaScript/Jquery. I didn't find anything on the internet.  That MUST be possible, right?

I don't need it to scroll on key up or down. I don't need a scroll Up, scroll down button. Only a little handle. I dont even need it to scroll with the mouse wheel.

Possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible using JavaScript. The libraries themselves are built using JavaScript, so if they can do it, of course you can. However, the advantage of using a library here is that it takes care of various other issues like browser incompatibilities.

Comment: Yup, its possible. If its possible with jQuery, its possible (by definition) with pure javascript. And here's an example where its done with jQuery:
http://baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/

Comment: If you don't want to use jQuery, then don't "spam-tag" your question with `jquery`.  Tag removed.

Comment: I never said I didnt want to use jquery. It's ok for me. Added the tag back and edited question so it's more clear

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it yourself, it would be something like this:

You define some styles:

```
* { padding:0; margin:0; }
.container { padding:0 10px; margin:0; background-color:#444; width:400px; height:400px; overflow:hidden; }
.scrollable { background-color:#5a5; width:100%; height:800px; position:relative; top:0; }
p { margin:0 0 30px 0; }
```

Then the html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="scrollable">
        <p>Line 1</p>
        <p>Line 2</p>
        <p>Line 3</p>
        <p>Line 4</p>
        <p>Line 5</p>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

And you can use Jquery to change the 'top' position of the element:

```
function scroll(target, x)
{
    $(target).animate({ top: x, duration: 2000});
}
```

You can call the function like this from a mouse scroll, a handler being moved or some other event:

```
scroll(".scrollable", "50%");
```

However, probably would be better to use an existing library that aready does it, as others pointed out, depending on your requirements.